# jQuery creating variables in a for loop or each loop from a multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array, dry

I'm working on my DRY techniques and I've been trying to figure out how I can declare variables from a multidimensional array if they exist without having to write a long declaration like this for up to five dimensions:

```
// dimension 1
var foo1x = bar[0][0],
    foo1y = bar[0][1],
    foo1z = bar[0][2];
```

I have searched through several questions on SO and I've tried this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < foobar.length; i++ ) {
    var foo + i + x,
        foo + i + y,
        foo + i + z;
}
```

and looked at objects with:

```
var value = {};
for ( var i = 0; i < foobar.length; i++ ) {
    $(foobar).each(function(i, e) {
        value["dimension" + i] = e;
    });
};
console.log(value);
```

but it isn't working as I need.  Is there a cleaner way to declaring variables used for a multidimensional array that I'm not seeing?  There could be 3 to 5 dimensions which is why I attempted to use `.length`.

Comment: Use a table and reference the rows and columns as objects

Comment: There's no real way to do what you're accomplishing AFAIK. Why do you want them all as individual variables anyway?

Comment: It's an interesting question, not sure why you need the variables though, just access the array when you need it.

Comment: I was wondering if this was possible which is why I wanted to create it.  I was looking at it not just from a multidimensional array but just as a solution from an evaluation stand-point without producing exuberant code.